# xDebug on Sublime text does not seem to be working properly

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublimetext, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug on a Vagrant guest Ubuntu 14.04 system and have set it up to work with SublimeText3 on my OSX host system.  I followed the instructions [here](http://mattwatson.codes/debug-php-vagrant-using-xdebug-sublime-text/).

Everything seems to kind of work but when I run Xdebug the breakpoint does not turn yellow and it is not clear what point in the code Xdebug is on, I do see the context panel though.

[image]

When I check the xDebug logs I see that it connects to the client and then says it can't connect to the client.

```
Log opened at 2016-03-31 08:08:59
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///vagrant/httpdocs/project-2/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2256" idekey="XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"><engine version="2.4.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -v 1 -n show_hidden
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -v 32 -n max_children
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -v 1024 -n max_data
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 4 -v 1 -n max_depth
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 5 -n 40 -f file%3A///var/www/project-2/index.php -t line
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="22560001"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -n 20 -f file%3A///Users/holy/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/project-1/app/design/frontend/hoi/default/template/page/html/header.phtml -t line
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="22560002"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 7 -x "Fatal error" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="22560003"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 8 -x "Catchable fatal error" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="22560004"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 9 -x "Warning" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="22560005"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 10 -x "Parse error" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="22560006"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 11 -x "Notice" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="22560007"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 12 -x "Strict standards" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="12" id="22560008"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 13 -x "Deprecated" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="13" id="22560009"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 14 -x "Xdebug" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="14" id="22560010"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 15 -x "Unknown error" -t exception
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="15" id="22560011"></response>

<- run -i 16
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="16" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///vagrant/httpdocs/project-2/index.php" lineno="40"></xdebug:message></response>

<- context_get -i 17 -c 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="17" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" type="array" children="1" numchildren="3" page="0" pagesize="32"><property name="__zlcmid" fullname="$_COOKIE[&#39;__zlcmid&#39;]" type="string" size="14" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WnBmUVZIclEzSWtiQmU=]]></property><property name="PHPSESSID" fullname="$_COOKIE[&#39;PHPSESSID&#39;]" type="string" size="26" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YWplcjAyaGh1bjVya2djZXBiaDc2cjFhbTU=]]></property><property name="XDEBUG_SESSION" fullname="$_COOKIE[&#39;XDEBUG_SESSION&#39;]" type="string" size="14" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WERFQlVHX0VDTElQU0U=]]></property></property><property name="$_ENV" fullname="$_ENV" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_FILES" fullname="$_FILES" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_GET" fullname="$_GET" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_POST" fullname="$_POST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_REQUEST" fullname="$_REQUEST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_SERVER" fullname="$_SERVER" type="array" children="1" numchildren="35" page="0" pagesize="32"><property name="SCRIPT_URL" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SCRIPT_URL&#39;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Lw==]]></property><property name="SCRIPT_URI" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SCRIPT_URI&#39;]" type="string" size="29" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aHR0cDovL2Rldi5kaWV0LWV4cGVydC5sb2NhbC8=]]></property><property name="HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_AUTHORIZATION&#39;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="HTTP_HOST" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_HOST&#39;]" type="string" size="21" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZGV2LmRpZXQtZXhwZXJ0LmxvY2Fs]]></property><property name="HTTP_CONNECTION" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_CONNECTION&#39;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[a2VlcC1hbGl2ZQ==]]></property><property name="HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL&#39;]" type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bWF4LWFnZT0w]]></property><property name="HTTP_ACCEPT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_ACCEPT&#39;]" type="string" size="74" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[dGV4dC9odG1sLGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL3hodG1sK3htbCxhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi94bWw7cT0wLjksaW1hZ2Uvd2VicCwqLyo7cT0wLjg=]]></property><property name="HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS&#39;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MQ==]]></property><property name="HTTP_USER_AGENT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_USER_AGENT&#39;]" type="string" size="120" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKE1hY2ludG9zaDsgSW50ZWwgTWFjIE9TIFggMTBfMTFfMikgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzQ5LjAuMjYyMy44NyBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2]]></property><property name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING&#39;]" type="string" size="19" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Z3ppcCwgZGVmbGF0ZSwgc2RjaA==]]></property><property name="HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE&#39;]" type="string" size="32" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZW4tVVMsZW47cT0wLjgsc3Y7cT0wLjYsZXM7cT0wLjQ=]]></property><property name="HTTP_COOKIE" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HTTP_COOKIE&#39;]" type="string" size="92" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[X196bGNtaWQ9WnBmUVZIclEzSWtiQmU7IFBIUFNFU1NJRD1hamVyMDJoaHVuNXJrZ2NlcGJoNzZyMWFtNTsgWERFQlVHX1NFU1NJT049WERFQlVHX0VDTElQU0U=]]></property><property name="PATH" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;PATH&#39;]" type="string" size="60" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Vzci9sb2NhbC9zYmluOi91c3IvbG9jYWwvYmluOi91c3Ivc2JpbjovdXNyL2Jpbjovc2JpbjovYmlu]]></property><property name="SERVER_SIGNATURE" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SERVER_SIGNATURE&#39;]" type="string" size="81" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[PGFkZHJlc3M+QXBhY2hlLzIuNC43IChVYnVudHUpIFNlcnZlciBhdCBkZXYuZGlldC1leHBlcnQubG9jYWwgUG9ydCA4MDwvYWRkcmVzcz4K]]></property><property name="SERVER_SOFTWARE" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SERVER_SOFTWARE&#39;]" type="string" size="21" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QXBhY2hlLzIuNC43IChVYnVudHUp]]></property><property name="SERVER_NAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SERVER_NAME&#39;]" type="string" size="21" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZGV2LmRpZXQtZXhwZXJ0LmxvY2Fs]]></property><property name="SERVER_ADDR" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SERVER_ADDR&#39;]" type="string" size="13" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTkyLjE2OC45OS45OQ==]]></property><property name="SERVER_PORT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SERVER_PORT&#39;]" type="string" size="2" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ODA=]]></property><property name="REMOTE_ADDR" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;REMOTE_ADDR&#39;]" type="string" size="12" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTkyLjE2OC45OS4x]]></property><property name="DOCUMENT_ROOT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;DOCUMENT_ROOT&#39;]" type="string" size="20" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Zhci93d3cvZGlldGF2ZW51ZS8=]]></property><property name="REQUEST_SCHEME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;REQUEST_SCHEME&#39;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aHR0cA==]]></property><property name="CONTEXT_PREFIX" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;CONTEXT_PREFIX&#39;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT&#39;]" type="string" size="20" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Zhci93d3cvZGlldGF2ZW51ZS8=]]></property><property name="SERVER_ADMIN" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SERVER_ADMIN&#39;]" type="string" size="23" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Y29udGFjdEBkaWV0LWV4cGVydC5jb20=]]></property><property name="SCRIPT_FILENAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SCRIPT_FILENAME&#39;]" type="string" size="29" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Zhci93d3cvZGlldGF2ZW51ZS9pbmRleC5waHA=]]></property><property name="REMOTE_PORT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;REMOTE_PORT&#39;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[NDk0MzY=]]></property><property name="GATEWAY_INTERFACE" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;GATEWAY_INTERFACE&#39;]" type="string" size="7" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Q0dJLzEuMQ==]]></property><property name="SERVER_PROTOCOL" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SERVER_PROTOCOL&#39;]" type="string" size="8" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[SFRUUC8xLjE=]]></property><property name="REQUEST_METHOD" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;REQUEST_METHOD&#39;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[R0VU]]></property><property name="QUERY_STRING" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;QUERY_STRING&#39;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="REQUEST_URI" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;REQUEST_URI&#39;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Lw==]]></property><property name="SCRIPT_NAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SCRIPT_NAME&#39;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2luZGV4LnBocA==]]></property></property></response>

<- context_get -i 18
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="18" context="0"><property name="$compilerConfig" fullname="$compilerConfig" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$mageFilename" fullname="$mageFilename" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$mageRunCode" fullname="$mageRunCode" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$mageRunType" fullname="$mageRunType" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$maintenanceFile" fullname="$maintenanceFile" type="uninitialized"></property></response>

<- stack_get -i 19
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="19"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///vagrant/httpdocs/project-2/index.php" lineno="40"></stack></response>

Log opened at 2016-03-31 08:09:06
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2016-03-31 08:09:06

Log opened at 2016-03-31 08:09:06
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2016-03-31 08:09:06

Log opened at 2016-03-31 08:09:06
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2016-03-31 08:09:06
```

I'm using 10.0.2.2 as the remote host in the php.ini file.

```
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
```

I just took this setting from the tutorial and it seems to work, first I tried 10.0.2.15 as it was the IP address I see when I vagrant ssh

```
IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.15
```

And also with ifconfig

```
vagrant@dev:/var/log/xdebug$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c9:24:d6  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec9:24d6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:118158 (118.1 KB)  TX bytes:157804 (157.8 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f4:70:ac  
          inet addr:192.168.99.99  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef4:70ac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1024 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1263 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:142856 (142.8 KB)  TX bytes:1993376 (1.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8804 (8.8 KB)  TX bytes:8804 (8.8 KB)
```

But xDebug does not connect at all when I use 10.0.2.15 as the remote host.

*/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini*

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host= 10.0.2.2 ; IDE-Environments IP, from vagrant box
```

*project.sublime-project*

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/Users/holy/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/project"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "xdebug": {
        "path_mapping": {
                 "/var/www/project" : "/Users/holy/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/project",
            },
        "url": "http://dev.project.local/",
        "super_globals": true,
        "close_on_stop": true
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

After trying suggested answer from @MarcinOrlowski it seems to be working from the logs but in Sublime the Breakpoint still does not turn yellow and I can not see what point in the code Xdebug is on in sublime.

```
Log opened at 2016-03-31 08:48:15
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.99.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///vagrant/httpdocs/project/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2626" idekey="XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"><engine version="2.4.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -v 1 -n show_hidden
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>
```

### Second Update

Some more details on the remote host...

```
vagrant@dev:~$ route | grep default | awk '{print $2}'
10.0.2.2
vagrant@dev:~$ telnet 10.0.2.2 9000
Trying 10.0.2.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
vagrant@dev:~$ tcpdump port 9000
tcpdump: no suitable device found
```

Comment: you forgot to include xdebug related php.ini entries

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I added the php.ini entries and also what I have in the .sublime-project file

Comment: `10.0.2.2` is the default host address. You can confirm it by running `route | grep default | awk '{print $2}'` from within the guest linux box. Check if ports are open. Try `telnet 10.0.2.2 9000` from within the linux box. It may worth to try `tcpdump port 9000` on host system.

Comment: @AlexBlex, Thanks.  I tried those commands and updated the results in my question.  It seems the telnet connection is being refused as the device is not found, am I reading that right?  What could be doing that?  I used hostmanager in my Vagrant file, could that have something to do with this I wonder

Comment: Yep, it seems the xdebug client is not listening, or the port is blocked. You can confirm it by running `lsof -i -P | grep 9000` **on host OSX**. If there is nothing, it's likely you did not start the debugger `Tools > Xdebug > Start Debugging` in Sublime.

Comment: @AlexBlex, nothing is shown when I run `lsof -i -P | grep 9000` on my OSX host.  I did and have started the debugger in sublime first, and the xdebuger context menu shows up

Comment: It should show [extra panels](http://mattwatson.codes/debug-php-vagrant-using-xdebug-sublime-text/#attachment_269) when you start the debugger. Not a context menu.

Comment: Sorry, I meant context panel. As in the image in my question. It show's the cookies etc

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I missed the part of the log where it actually managed to connect to the client first time. Evidently the client stopped listening at some point. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove `remote_host` entry but add `remote_connect_back` instead ([docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)):

> If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting is ignored and Xdebug will
>   try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request.

So this should do the trick (and you may need to restart httpd on vagrant first)

```
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.remote_start = on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"
```

BTW: `zend_extension` path can be relative if you got [extension_dir](https://secure.php.net/manual/pl/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) set correctly.

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

Comment: thanks that helped but I'm still having some issues.  See my updated question.  I'm not sure what you mean by the `extension_dir`, how can I check if my system is using that?  Do I need to change the path I've set to xdebug.so?

Comment: Please do not change question scope. Accept my answer if that solved your problem and post another question in regards of your next issue

Comment: I haven't changed the scope of the question.  I up-voted your answer as it was helpful (thank you) and the xDebug logs are now showing something different.  I think it would be disingenuous if I marked this as the correct answer when the issue I'm having persists, i.e. when I run Xdebug the breakpoint does not show in SublimeText properly